# Why does egrep not find white space correctly in history listing?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have this in my command history:

```
  280  ls -l | egrep -v '^d'
  348  ls -l | egrep '^d'
  375  git help ls-tree
  376  git ls-tree
  377  git ls-tree HEAD
  378  git ls-tree HEAD^
  379  git ls-tree HEAD system
  380  git ls-tree HEAD system/
  381  git ls-tree HEAD^ system/
  460  ls
  463  ls
  464  ls /*
  465  ls */
  466  ls -d */
  468  ls -d */
  469  ls -d *
```

I can list all commands that end with `/` like this:

```
history | egrep "/$"
```

But if I want to list all commands that start with `ls`, and I type this:

```
history | egrep "^\s*\d*\s*ls"
```

It returns nothing.

However, if I the output the text to a file and copy the output to regex101.com, then this regex correctly finds all commands that start with `ls`.

Is there some other variable I need to use other than `\s` to identify whitespace in the output with egrep?

Comment: There is no `\d` in ERE. You'll have to use GNU grep with PCRE  `-P` or use `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: Thanks @muru, `history | grep -P "^\s*\d*\s*ls"` worked.